# xpages action button intermittent behavior

Tags: xpages

I have a problem that happens intermittently with the buttons that perform some action, be they simple actions or not. Intermittently clicking the button nothing happens and no error is displayed in the Domino server log.

The buttons are in a custom control that is added to xpage. Basically the xpage is composed by 3 custom control:

A page layout that uses an application layout. In that was included directly an navigatior

One to display the contents of the document that has a form table.

One that owns the buttons with actions. This is included in the facet header of the form table quoted above.

Has anyone ever had this problem? Would it be some setting on some application property or domino server?

Grateful!

Marcus Loza

Comment: Could it be a session timeout issue? Does it only happen after x minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are multiple developers working on the same NSF? If so, a build will clear all files associated to the application, including the component trees for the page. That means your buttons will fail to work, because it can't find the component tree for the page, from which to trigger the event.

This can particularly be a problem if Build Automatically is switched on. Recommended practice is for each developer to work on their own instance or a local replica.

Alternatively, if you're the only developer, make sure you refresh the browser whenever you build the application. The build process removes all server-side persistence of current pages, which affects any current browser pages subsequently trying a partial refresh.

Comment: Not only I am developing the application. The Build Automatically option is enabled.

Comment: If you make a change and build, you'll need to reload the page in the browser for buttons to work, is this the problem?

Comment: That is not the case, even without making any changes the problem occurs.

Comment: Hello Paul! You were right!
I noticed that the problem happens when I make some modification in the application and it is already open in the browser. Please respond to the questioning so I can accept your response. Thanks a lot!